# How to show error message until input (text) is properly formatted URL? In Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm very new to angular js so please excuse me if this is trivial.  But I want to be able to show an error message for a specific text area until the user inputs a valid URL.  I don't know what I'm missing, but I'm very close. I just can't seem to make the error message go away after the user actually inputs a correct input.

For example, sample.com is valid, and the error should go away. 'sample.c' is not valid and the message should be present.  This is my main area of focus for now, but I would also like to know how to keep the message hidden initially, that is it should not show up until they actually start typing.  This is what I have so far:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-style="clip.clipStyle">
      <div class="form-group">
        <form action="/update"  method="POST">
          <input type="text" name = "userURL" class="form-control preview-input" ng-model="clip.link" id="link_{{clip.ordering}}" ng-blur="loadTitle(clip, $event); showUpload(clip);" e-maxlength="2000" placeholder='<spring:message code="journalist.clip.link.placeholder"/>'
          <span style="color:red" ng-show = "!validUrl()">
           Sorry Not a Valid URL.</span>
        </form>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Here is my script:

```
$scope.validUrl = function () {
   return CommonUtils.isValidUrl($scope.url);
};
```

isValidUrl(String) is functional, as it works other places.  I appreciate any input.  Thanks!

1) When ng-show = validUrl()
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h12UE.png)

2) When ng-show = !validUrl()
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHgL5.png)

in these snippets, in 1.) nothing will enable the text box and in 2.) nothing will make the text color change from red nor will the message below the text box go away.

Answer (score 1):

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andymerts/xt8k0q73/) to show how this should work.  I don't have your CommonUtils, or the rest of the controller or page, so I created a **very** basic example.  It appears to be working as desired in the fiddle, so hopefully this will show something either missing or wrong in your implementation.

```js
var app = angular.module("sample", [])
.controller("sampleController", function ($scope) {
 var regex = /^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/;
  $scope.url = "http://google.com";
  $scope.isValid = function (text) {
   return regex.test(text);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sample">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="url" />
    <span style="color: red;" ng-hide="isValid(url)">The url is invalid</span>
  </div>
</div>
```